# Formatting multiple equations in one displaymath line?

Tags: spacing, equations

If I want to write multiple equations in the same line in displaymath mode, I would do something like this:

```
\[
a + b = c
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
```

But I know it's not good to rely on manual spacing. Is there a better way to get the same effect?

Comment: This is not manual spacing and is indeed the recommended way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think your solution is fine, in particular, since it is only one line of equations. Other than that, groups of equations next to each other can be obtained with `align`, or `alignat` from the `amsmath` package. Note however, that these two environments add more space above and below the equations. Compare:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\hrule
\[
  a + b = c \qquad\text{and}\qquad a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\]
\hrule

\bigskip

\hrule
\begin{equation*}
  a + b = c \qquad\text{and}\qquad a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation*}
\hrule

\bigskip

\hrule
\begin{align*}
  a + b &= c  &\text{and } a^2 + b^2 &= c^2
\end{align*}
\hrule
\bigskip

\hrule
\begin{alignat*}{2}
  a + b &= c  &\qquad\text{and}\qquad a^2 + b^2 &= c^2
\end{alignat*}
\hrule
\end{document}
```

leading to
[image]

Comment: my inclination would be, in this case, to put the `\quad`s within the `\text`; the visual result is the same.  also, this is an excellent demonstration of why it's not a good idea to use one of the `align` structures for a one-line equation, which is (too) often recommended.